# which cleos command is used to transfer tokens

Tags: cleos

> I am developing a wallet service for eosio, and i want to transfer tokens, how can i do this.

I have used cleos for account creation

```
cleos create account eosio  mynewacct1 EOSxxxxxxxxxxxxxx EOSxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Now i want to transfer eos , can anyone explain how can do this?

Answer (score 2):

The command to transfer EOS with `cleos` is as follows:

```
cleos transfer from to quantity memo
```

An example of transferring 12.5 EOS from account12345 to account54321:

```
cleos transfer account12345 account54321 "12.5 EOS" "This is the money I owe you for giving great answers on StackExchange"
```

You can also do a transfer by directly calling the appropriate action in the `eosio.token` contract as follows (equivalent to above):

```
cleos push action eosio.token transfer '{"from":"account12345","to":"account54321","quantity":"12.5000 EOS","memo":"This is the money I owe you for giving great answers on StackExchange"}' -p account12345@active
```

**or**

```
cleos push action eosio.token transfer '["account12345","account54321","12.5000 EOS","This is the money I owe you for giving great answers on StackExchange"]' -p account12345@active
```

Note that the quantity in the second example(s) has to be given to the *correct number of decimal places* for the precision of the token being transferred, for EOS, **that is 4 decimal places.**

Answer (score 0):

You should take a deeper look at the eos.io-documentation and the differences between using **Cleos** and the **RPC-API**.

- [EOSIO Developer Portal](https://developers.eos.io/)
- [Cleos Reference](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference)
- [RPC Reference](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference)

You can find the cleos command for a transfer here: **[Cleos Transfer](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-transfer)**